# How to find out that device was connected to the phone with audio jack 3.5?

Tags: android, audio

I work on application for Android. How I can know if user connected headphones or some other devices to the phone? I have no idea about it! Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening in a Broadcast receiver for `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG for more info.